# Callback for change in URL in Ember v1.0.pre

Tags: ember.js

I want to call a function when their is a change in URL. 
In newer versions of Ember, we can do this by observing `currentPath`. 
In this version, I tried this:

```
Ember.Route.reopen({
  enter: function(router) {
    console.log('change in URL and need to be called once per change in URL');
  }
});
```

Since there are nested routes, so this method was called mutiple times.

Comment: why you don't swith to the current version then? ember is about to reach 1.0 so I guess you are better of on doing the switch as soon a possible to remain without bugs and problems in the future...

Comment: @intuitivepixel: any suggestions with this version

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using `Ember.HashLocation` you can do this, observing `lastSetURL` property:

```
window.App = Ember.Application.create({
  ...
  urlChanged: function(a,b,c,d) {
    var url = this.get('router.location.lastSetURL');
      if (!Ember.none(url)) {
        alert(url);
      }    
  }.observes('router.location.lastSetURL'),
  ...
});
```

Here is a example of this working http://jsfiddle.net/marciojunior/ba4hJ/